# DQN model choosing actions with variable parameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to code a DQN model for a card game. I am facing the problem, that my agent chooses an action, and then based on the action it either has to chose no card, one card or a list of cards aswell. The q_values are always calculated for what action the agent should chose, so I cannot use these q_values to chose a card. Creating actions for each card is I think not possible. One reason for it is that the game is pretty complex with potentially a lot of cards, and the second is that the amounts of cards to choose from is always different. It can range from lets say 25 to 70 cards. The cards are also very hard to sort in any way. That would make the action space different for every time the agent choses an action, which I think is bad for the learning of the model.

I know that it cannot work how I set it up right now but to show you, I currently have it setup like this:

```
if random.random() > epsilon:
            action_index = np.argmax(q_values)
            action = self.actions_to_chose_from[action_index]
            end = time.time()
            #print(f"chose_action took: {end - start}")
            return action
else:
            action = random.choice(self.actions_to_chose_from)
            end = time.time()
            #print(f"chose_action took: {end - start}")
            return action
```

```
 def take_action(self, action):
        last_state = self.get_state()
        chosen_cards = []
        q_values = agent.get_q_values(last_state)

        all_cards = self.clickable_cards
        all_cards_2 = []

        try:
            action()

        except:
            try:
                for _ in all_cards:
                    if epsilon < random.random():
                        try:
                            card_index = np.argmax(q_values)
                            card = all_cards[card_index]
                        except:
                            card = None
                    else:
                        try:
                            card = random.choice(all_cards)
                        except:
                            card = None

                    if card is not None:
                        chosen_cards.append(card)
                        all_cards.remove(card)

                action(chosen_cards)

            except:
                self.reset_cards_elements()
                for card in self.clickable_cards_e:
                    card = self.card_to_int(card)
                    if card is not None:
                        all_cards_2.append(card)
                if epsilon < random.random():
                    try:
                        card_index = np.argmax(q_values)
                        card = all_cards_2[card_index]
                    except:
                        card = None
                else:
                    try:
                        card = random.choice(all_cards_2)
                    except:
                        card = None

                if card is not None:
                    action(card)
```

Possible solutions I have thought of:

Now first of all I am not sure if there may be a better way to create an AI for a card game than with deep q learning. It is the best way I have found while googling it anyways but if you know a better way let me know.

I thought about if it would be a good idea to either have the DQN model create 2 q_values, one for the actions and the second for the parameters. I also thought about creating a second agent just for the parameters.I haven't tried these thoughts because i am not sure if they are really possible and if they would be a good idea if they were.

At last i have thought about if there is a way to make the agent choose from an actions space with an always changing size. I couldn't find anything and like i already said I am not sure if the model would be able to learn with an approach like this. But if there would be a way, I could probably create an action specific for each card.